# Where is MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME in Android?

Tags: java, android, video, media, mediastore

According to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=lv on android developers, where the `MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` appears near the begin of this article, I try to find the constant **DISPLAY_NAME** through  a link on the `MediaStore.Video.Media` class (which is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Media) and I can't find the **DISPLAY_NAME** constant here. Where can I find this to see according meaning and description of this constant ?

Comment: perhaps it should be _DISPLAY_NAME, it is a column in the table files

Comment: They use these things as in the next example:   MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE. Perhaps they mean that you have said i.e. all of those are columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/providers/MediaProvider/apex/framework/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java?q=MediaStore.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject&hl=ko

```
public final class MediaStore {

    public static final class Video {
 
        public interface VideoColumns extends MediaColumns {

        public static final class Media implements VideoColumns {
```

It means that "MediaStore.Video.Media" extends MediaColumns.
And MediaColumns has DISPLAY_NAME

```
public interface MediaColumns extends BaseColumns {
    public static final String DISPLAY_NAME = "_display_name";
```